# How to add multiple Objects into an Array inside an Object

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

My code below will add the last generated Object into the phones array of the Person object. What I'm trying to do is be able to add all the generated Objects into the phones array.

```
var person = {
    username : username,
    phones : []
}

// Added Profile
var phoneObjs   = {};
var addedPhones = $('.added_phone');
```

The function that loops through all the new .added_phone input values:

```
addedPhones.each( function(i) {
    var tag = $(this).children("label").text();
    var value = $(this).children("input").val();
    phoneObjs = $(this).map(function(i,el) {
        var $el = $(el);
        return {
            tag: tag,
            label: value
        }
    }).get();

    console.log(phoneObjs);

    person.phones = phoneObjs;
    // person.phones.push(phoneObjs);

    console.log(person.phones);
});
```

I'll create 2 new input fields and enter 2 different numbers, next I submit the form and run the function above. From the chrome console `console.log(person.phones)`:

[image]

The 2nd time it loops around, the first Object gets replaced

[image]

How would you avoid this problem?

Comment: Why you have commented the push call?

Comment: try concat like `person.phones = person.phones.concat(phoneObjs);`

Comment: @MinkoGechev the push ended up creating an Array inside of an Array inside and Object. Instead of Object in Array in Object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In ES5

```
person.phones = person.phones.concat(phoneObjs);
```

In ES6:

```
person.phones = [...person.phones,...phoneObjs];
```

Comment: Thanks! That was it :) I tried `push`, but ended up putting Arrays inside of the phone Array instead of objects